# css jquery + lightbox work only one of them

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I use lightboxon selected pictures and jquery on selected buttons.

[image]

But works only one of jscripts.

Code:

```
    <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 

<a href="blg.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="News Blog" target="_blank";/>
<img src="http://my.jetscreenshot.com/10682/20120401-qcva-4kb.jpg" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/></a>
```

Now work only jquery. Only buttons.
But when I delete this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

then will work litebox.
That is why I got a problem.. how to use bouth of them?
If you have any ideas help me pls.

Answer (score 1):

order of inclusion of js files does matter, include the jquery first

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also check that the plugin is compatible with the latest version of the jQuery(1.7), try using some older versions like `1.5`

Comment: Done. Now buttons don't work, but litebox is working. Need to work bouth.